# how to make a continous loop with second while statement

Tags: c++

okay here is my code for a game called pig. I having trouble because the code for the computers turn will only got through one time and once the second turn is reached  the first line is only printed. is there any soluction to this or am I just screwed?

```
`int main () {

  int humanTurn=0;
  int humanTotalScore=0;
  int computerTotalScore=0;
  int computerTurn=3;
  float diceRoll = 0;
  int score = 0;
  int computerScore = 0;
  int answer = 0;
  int humanScore = 0;
  int pause = 0;
  float computerDiceRoll = 0;


    srand(time(0));



    cout << "Welcome to the game of pig, the first player to reach to 100 wins."<< endl;
    cout << "if you roll a one no score will be recorded and your turn will go the computer"<< endl;
    cout << " If you choose to hold, the total score accumilated will be recorded" << endl;






  while ((humanTotalScore < 100) && (computerTotalScore < 100)) {
     cout << endl;
     cout << endl;
     cout << "press 1 to  roll or 2 to save your score: ";
     cin >> answer;


  for (int i=0; i<1; i++) {
    diceRoll = rand() % 6 + 1;

  }



 if ((diceRoll > 1) && ( answer == 1)){
    cout << endl;
    cout << endl;
    cout << "your  current roll is: " << diceRoll << endl; 
    cout << endl;
    cout << endl;


      score += diceRoll;
     cout << "Score for this turn is: " << score << endl;
     cout << "your total score is: " << humanTotalScore << endl;
    cout << endl;
    cout << endl;
    }
 else if (answer == 2){
   cout << "your score of: " << score << " will be saved" << endl;
   humanTotalScore += score;
   score = 0;


} 

 else {
  cout << endl;
  cout << endl;
  cout << "you  rolled a ONE. You lose your turn and any points that were with it" <<endl;
  cout << endl;
  cout << endl;

  score = 0;
  computerTurn = score;
  }
  if ((computerTurn == 0) || (answer == 2)){




    computerDiceRoll = rand() % 6 + 1;
```

here is code that is giving me loop problems.

```
    while ((computerDiceRoll > 1)&& (computerScore <= 20)){

    if (computerDiceRoll == 1){
     computerScore = 0;
     computerTurn = 1;
     cout << "Computer rolled a ONE, it is now your turn." << endl;
 }

      computerDiceRoll = rand() % 6 + 1;
      cout << endl;
      cout << endl;
      cout << "computers roll is : " << computerDiceRoll << endl; 
      cout << endl;
      cout << endl;

      computerScore += computerDiceRoll;
      if (computerScore >20){
        computerTotalScore += computerScore;
        computerTurn = 1;
      }

      cout << "computer current score is : " << computerScore << endl;
      cout << "computer total score is: " << computerTotalScore << endl;
      cout << endl;
      cout << endl;

     }
    }

  }
 } `
```

Comment: It might be easier to figure out what's going wrong if you break this function into smaller functions. For example, make the human and computer turns each be a separate function.